Absolute imports error in Vite Typescript
I try use absolute imports in my project.
tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["./src*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["src"]

vite.config.ts
resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  }

My project works, and my ide find import file, but i get error TS2307: Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations.
i tried install npm package vite-tsconfig-paths and add plugin tsconfigPaths()

My tsconfig.json file references tsconfig.app.json.
I didn't notice the tsconfig.app.json file, so that file overrode my tsconfig.json.
